# There was a temporary error when trying to login to game account through facebook

Tags: facebook, google-play-games

As the title says, whenever I try to login to any game through the facebook option it throws out the there was a temporary error error code:FFFFFF and it's been like this for days now. I have no idea why this happens or what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

So I need more details for helping you, but consider to make a screenshot and send it to the manufacturer. Send him wich Phone you have(Phone with model, Android version, ram, rom etc.)

Hopefully he wil help you, and for the time in between you can try to download an APK from another mirror(try several versions...) Or just login without Facebook.